# How does a MVC4 website target a specific client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am designing a website for an intranet where I will push data to a specific client (browser) using signalR.

I understand that in ASP.NET MVC4, each client that connects to the server will create a new object ie a new instance of the controller class. However how do I 'address' a specific controller instance in c#, so I can send new data to a specific client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

In SignalR, you use the `ClientId` to send to a specific client. You don't target a `Controller`. Your website is just a host for all of this.. it doesn't care about your specific implementation (such as the existence of individual controllers for individual clients).

So, if you want to send to a specific user, you track their `ClientId` in your `Hub`, and push data out to that client. Or, without persistent connections, you can have the client generate a token to track them with.

I'm pretty sure newer versions of SignalR allow you to take control of how the `ClientId` is generated. This allows you to track it however you want without a persistent connection (since `ClientId` will be different per connection without a persistent connection).

Comment: Thanks. ALso found more about it here... http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server